# Jquery modal plugin

Tags: html, javascript, jquery

In my web application i have one page call it mypage.html
When user clicks some link in mypage a modal window will be opened and he will see some html page.
(I do this by Colorbox or Twitter Bootstrap now)

But when user clicked a button in modal window, an Ajax request will be sent to my server. If request is successfull he will see some new modal window, else user will see another modal window. After all steps user will close modal window and tasks will be finished.

Which jquery modal window plugin is suitable for this type of usage?

Answer (score 2):

I think the [jQuery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog) (with its modal option) would be more than sufficient. With regards to implementation, that question might be best asked over at [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation Look at the buttons options, your ajax call would be triggered by the click definition.

Comment: @iKnowKungFoo thats pretty much the way to go using AJAX, onclick, and callbacks to keep the modal open until the user's finished doing whatever they need to.